# MySQL Workbench - SELECT is not valid at this position with this server version when using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench, case-statement

When implementing a basic CASE WHEN statement in MySQL Workbench, I am getting the following error "SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version. Expecting FOR, LOCK, TABLES, VALUES, WITH, '('".

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT mode_dsc, Weight, rate, min_cost, 
CASE 
    WHEN (Weight*rate) < min_cost THEN min_cost AS Cost
    WHEN (Weight*rate) > min_cost THEN (Weight*rate) AS Cost
END AS Cost
FROM OrderLineRate
WHERE mode_dsc = "AIR";
```

The OrderLineRate table consists of the following:

| OrderID | ProductID | mode_dsc | Weight | minm_wgh_qty | max_wgh_qty | rate | min_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1447133055 | 1678648 | AIR | 1.463 | 0 | 99.99 | $0.05 | $1.50 |

Software: MySQL Workbench (version 8.0.22.CE) to interact with a MySQL Server(version 8.0.22)

Comment: as cost is only appropriate after the end of the case.

Comment: I have voted to close this as a simple typo question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as cost is only appropriate after the end of the case.

```
SELECT mode_dsc, Weight, rate, min_cost, 
CASE 
    WHEN (Weight*rate) < min_cost THEN min_cost 
    WHEN (Weight*rate) > min_cost THEN (Weight*rate) 
END AS Cost
FROM OrderLineRate
WHERE mode_dsc = "AIR";
```